# Sort a Julia 1.1 matrix by one of its columns, that contains strings

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, julia

As the title suggests, I need to sort the rows of a certain matrix by one of its columns, preferably in place if at all possible. Said column contains `String`s (the array being of type `Array{Union{Float64,String}}`), and ideally the rows should end up in an alphabetial order, determined by this column. The line

```
sorted_rows = sort!(data, by = i -> data[i,2]),
```

where `data` is my matrix, produces the error `ERROR: LoadError: UndefKeywordError: keyword argument dims not assigned`. Specifying which part of the matrix I want sorted and adding the parameter `dims=2` (which I assume is the dimension I want to sort along), namely

```
sorted_rows = sort!(data[2:end-1,:], by = i -> data[i,2],dims=2)
```

simply changes the error message to `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: invalid index: 01 Suurin yhteinen tekijä ja pienin yhteinen jaettava of type String`. So the compiler is complainig about a string being an invalid index.

Any ideas on how this type of sorting cound be done? I should say that in this case the string in the column can be expected to start with a number, but I wouldn't mind finding a solution that works in the general case.

I'm using Julia 1.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `sortslices`, not `sort` — the latter just sorts all columns independently, whereas the former rearranges whole slices.  Secondly, the `by` function doesn't take an *index*, it takes the *value* that is about to be compared (and allows you to transform it in some way).  Thus:

```
julia> using Random
       data = Union{Float64, String}[randn(100) [randstring(10) for _ in 1:100]]
100×2 Array{Union{Float64, String},2}:
  0.211015  "6VPQbWU5f9"
 -0.292298  "HgvHLkufqI"
  1.74231   "zTCu1U5Vdl"
  0.195822  "O3j43sbhKV"
  ⋮
 -0.369007  "VzFH2OpWfU"
 -1.30459   "6C68G64AWg"
 -1.02434   "rldaQ3e0GE"
  1.61653   "vjvn1SX3FW"

julia> sortslices(data, by=x->x[2], dims=1)
100×2 Array{Union{Float64, String},2}:
  0.229143  "0syMQ7AFgQ"
 -0.642065  "0wUew61bI5"
  1.16888   "12PUn4V4gL"
 -0.266574  "1Z2ONSBP04"
  ⋮
  1.85761   "y2DDANcFCe"
  1.53337   "yZju1uQqMM"
  1.74231   "zTCu1U5Vdl"
  0.974607  "zdiU0sVOZt"
```

Unfortunately we don't have an in-place `sortslices!` yet, but you can easily construct a sorted view with `sortperm`. This probably won't be as fast to use, but if you need the in-place-ness for semantic reasons it'll do just the trick.

```
julia> p = sortperm(data[:,2]);

julia> @view data[p, :]
100×2 view(::Array{Union{Float64, String},2}, [26, 45, 90, 87, 6, 96, 82, 75, 12, 27  …  53, 69, 100, 93, 36, 37, 39, 8, 3, 61], :) with eltype Union{Float64, String}:
  0.229143  "0syMQ7AFgQ"
 -0.642065  "0wUew61bI5"
  1.16888   "12PUn4V4gL"
 -0.266574  "1Z2ONSBP04"
  ⋮
  1.85761   "y2DDANcFCe"
  1.53337   "yZju1uQqMM"
  1.74231   "zTCu1U5Vdl"
  0.974607  "zdiU0sVOZt"
```

(If you want the in-place-ness for performance reasons, I'd recommend using a DataFrame or similar structure that holds its columns as independent homogenous vectors — a `Union{Float64, String}` will be slower than two separate well-typed vectors, and `sort!`ing a DataFrame works on whole rows like you want.)

Comment: Great answer, as usual... But, I wonder why all you guys with the brilliant answers never upvote the questions... if it's worth answering, might it not be worth an upvote as well‽

Comment: Yes, that's a good reminder. I often just find myself upvoting questions I want the answers to, but you're right — good questions deserve upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look at `SortingLab.jl`s fast string sort functions.

```
]add SortingLab
using SortingLab
idx = fsortperm(data[:,2])
new_data = data[idx]
```